# Error when Scraping data from a given website

Tags: excel, vba, object, error-handling

I'am new to vba in excel. I managed to write a code which scrapes data from a given website and stores it in an excel worksheet. The code works almost every time i run it but sometimes i get an error:

> Object variable or With block variable not set.

So it is very challenging to find out why. Also if you could help me out speeding the code (maybe not using clipboard to pastspecial the table, but I don't know how to use otherwise...). Also for you to know, once the error is promted if I click end and run the sub again, it runs without any problem. The error is promted (sometimes only, most of the time the sub works fine) in the specified line with this comment: 'This is the line which throws the error. I appreciate any kind of help guys, thank you in advance :).
The sub looks like this:

```
Sub PaData()
Dim c As Object, D As Object, H As Object, PID$, SD As Date, FC$, cf$

Set c = CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
Set D = CreateObject("HTMLFile")
Set H = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")

FC = "EXA"         ' This is used to generate the website url
cf = VBMa   ' This is another sub which works fine and i need it to get into the webiste

' Get the page
H.SetAutoLogonPolicy 0
H.SetClientCertificate "CURRENT_USER\MY\" & Environ("USERNAME")
H.Open "GET", "https://confidentialwebsite=" & FC
H.setRequestHeader "Cookie", cf
H.Send
H.waitForResponse

' Put the response into the HTML object
D.body.innerHTML = H.ResponseText
' Copy _only a given Table
c.setText D.getElementByID("giventable").outerHTML 'This is the line which throws the error
c.PutInClipBoard

' Paste into the sheet, remove hyperlinks and unMerge all data
Sheets("Pdata").Cells.Delete
Sheets("Pdata").[A1].PasteSpecial
Sheets("Pdata").Cells.Hyperlinks.Delete
Sheets("Pdata").Cells.UnMerge
'update time
Sheets("SM").Range("B1").Value = Sheets("Pdata").Range("D2").Value + 2 / 24

End Sub
```

Comment: You should show on which lined of code this error occurs. Now the reader here has to guess what might be wrong because they cannot access the `confidentialwebsite`.

Comment: Also you should check for errors. After `H.Send` you should check for `H.Status` (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms767681(v=vs.85))

Comment: @Luuk Thank you for your interest. Please read again as the line in which the error occurs it is already clarified. Both in the explanation of the error and in the code with a comment 'This is the line in which the error occurs. I hope you can find it now :)

Comment: @Luuk Thanks again! I checked the H.status and the times the sub failed it was due to an "internal server error" (H.status = 500). I solved this error by adding If H.Status <> 200 Then GoTo tryagain. And tryagain fores to open the webpage again. I dont know how to mark your comment as valid answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

When doing an HTTPRequest to a webserver, you should *always* verify the return status of this call using `.Status`  (see: [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms767681(v=vs.85)) )

An overview of the possible status numbers can be found here: https://httpstatuses.com/ or here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#1xx_Informational_response